# How to create Viewmodel for subview and update values on change in Swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Currently i am using subview without using viewmodel and which is woking fine..UI is updating on value change. (find code below) but i want to create viewmodel for subview and update UI on value change..

Normal code without viewmodel

```
struct MainView: View {

    @State private var selectedTag: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(products, id: \.description) { item in
                SubView(productTag: item.productId, selectedTag: self.$selectedTag)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SubView: View {

    var productTag: String?
    @Binding var selectedTag: String?

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            self.selectedTag = self.productTag
        })
    }
}
```

with viewmodel (but not working for me - UI is not updating)

```
struct MainView: View {

    @State private var selectedTag: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(products, id: \.description) { item in
                SubView(viewModel: SubViewViewModel(productTag: item.productId ?? "", selectedTag: self.selectedTag ?? ""))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {

    private var viewModel: SubViewViewModel

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            viewModel.selectedTag = viewModel.productTag
        })
    }
}

class SubViewViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var productTag: String
    @Published var selectedTag: String?

    init(productTag: String, selectedTag: String) {
        self.productTag = productTag
        self.selectedTag = selectedTag
    }
}
```

I might missing some concept, kindly suggest the solution for same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `SubView` to alter `MainView` via a shared model you will first need to initialize it as a `@StateObject` on the `MainView`, because `MainView` is the owner.

Then you pass that same viewModel to `SubView` as an `@ObservedObject` since `SubView` is only borrowing it.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(products, id: \.description) { item in
                SafHelpCard(viewModel: viewModel, productTag: item.productId)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.onAppear(/* whatever setup is needed */)
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    let productTag: String?

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            viewModel.selectedTag = viewModel.productTag
        })
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTag: String?

    func onAppear(args:...) {
        // do required setup in here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but still values in Mainview is not updating do i need to do anything in Mainview ?

Comment: Ok I originally misunderstood your question. It seems like you want to share a viewModel. In that case you need to pass the same instance of `ViewModel` to the subviews. I took the liberty of renaming it.

Comment: How can i pass values to viewmodel from Mainview?

Comment: Create a function on your viewModel that accepts the arguments you need. Call it in `onAppear` on your view.

Comment: @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel( // how can i pass init data here? )

Comment: You don't pass it in directly. SwiftUI views are initialized unpredictably. Instead you would do whatever setup is needed in `onAppear`, `onChange` or a similar callback. I updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: If I use class for Viewmodel i need to create init method and has to pass parameters ... here - @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel( // how can i pass init data here? )

Answer (score 0):

Make your view model a singleton.

```
struct MainView: View {
@StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel.shared

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(products, id: \.description) { item in
            SafHelpCard(viewModel: viewModel, productTag: item.productId)
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        viewModel.onAppear(/* whatever setup is needed */)
    }
}
}

struct SubView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel.shared
let productTag: String?

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        viewModel.selectedTag = viewModel.productTag
    })
}
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var selectedTag: String?
static var shared = ViewModel()

func onAppear(args:...) {
    // do required setup in here
}
}
```

Comment: Yadda yadda "singleton is a crutch... ". I don't hate on 'em, but you know you're gonna hear that eventually if you use one :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create `ViewModel` on `SubView` to update value from `MainView`, but rather pass down `ViewModel` from `MainView` to `SubView`

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTag: String?
    var products: [Product]
}

struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.products, id: \.description) { item in
                SubView(viewModel: viewModel, product: item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MainViewModel
    var product: Product
    var body: some View {
        Button(product.productTag) {
            mainModel.selectedTag = product.productTag
        }.onAppear {
            // Do can do things to viewModel when SubView on appear here
        }
    }
}
```

If your `SubView` has some business that doesn't want to bother `MainView`, and you only need `selectedTag` from `MainView`, you should keep using `@Binding` and create a `@StateObject private var viewModel` inside `SubView`

Comment: I want it to be update

Comment: that's more normal, i've updated my answer on that

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the view model as an environment object to your subview like this or use a Binding variable as well.

Since you are using @State, which only works with simple data types. For the view to be updated as per your view model, you need to use @StateObject as viewmodel is a complex data type.

Please check this link: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/state-vs-stateobject-vs-observedobject-vs-environmentobject-in-swiftui-81e2913d63f9

```
 class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
     @Published var name: String = "Test"
 }

 struct MainView: View {

     @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

     var body: some View {
         ChildView()
             .environmentObject(viewModel)
     }
 }


 struct ChildView: View {

     @EnvironmentObject var model: ViewModel

     var body: some View {
         Text(model.name)
     }
 }
```

Comment: but how can i pass parameters here?  @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
as i must have to create init method in for class Viewmodel

Comment: Also how should i pass parameters from  .environmentObject(viewModel), how can pass values from main view to subview

Comment: You can implement init() method of the view model class 

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = nm
    }
}

Then you can pass in the parameters in your main class. Plus if in case you need to change value at time of passing down the value in your child view, you can create a method in your view model and call it before passing it as environment object.